# SqlDataReader - more readable code

Tags: vb.net

If you know a `SqlDataReader` contains one row then you can do this:

```
If objDR.HasRows() Then
objDR.read
.........
End If
```

Instead of this:

```
Do While objDR.Read
..........
loop
```

If you use a `DataTable` then it appears you have to do this:

```
For Each row as DataRow In objDT.Rows
...................
Next
```

Is there anything you can do with `SqlDataReader` if there is only one row? I am asking as I believe it makes code more readable.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are looking for. You have that first code sample - what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: Another developer more senior than I looked at some code and criticized the approach of enumerating a datatable because only one row would ever be returned (guaranteed) by the underlying query.  I don't understand what the alternative is (must use a DataTable).

Comment: IMO the other dev's opinion is entirely subjective. Arguably,*not* relying on the query only ever returning one row is better/more defensive programming than assuming it always will return precisely one. ETA I see DavidW simultaneously made much the same point in his 2nd para

Comment: FYI SQLreader (and others maybe) have SingleRow command for the reader:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
If objDR.Read() Then
  .........
End If
```

Comment: Thanks.  I know you can do this.  I can't use a datareader because they don't outlive the connection.  Is there similar syntax for a DataTable.

Comment: @w0051977 Your question was about DataReaders.  You might want to update your question to DataTables then.  You don't *read* DataTables like DataReaders, you access them, so you would just do `dataTable.Rows(0)` to access the first (or only) row.

Comment: I think dataTable.Rows(0) was what I was looking for.  Thanks.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
If objDT IsNot Nothing AndAlso objDT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    ' We have one or more rows
    For Each row as DataRow In objDT.Rows
        ' Do something with row here
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered situations like this, where your code will be guaranteed to generate exactly one single result row, and I tend to agree that instantiation of an enumerator for that row isn't ideal. In fact, I've seen a few apps where single-row (or even single-column) result sets were in use, and the authors wrote some very simple wrapper class methods that were designed to take an arbitrary single-result query and return it in a single call, packaging up the overhead of the call, parameters, etc. in a neat, clean single method.

In that case, I actually think its a good case to check the Count property for the rows, and if its non-one, throw an exception. If you've got a query that's forever and always supposed to return exactly one value, but more show up, something's wrong.

```
if (objDT != null && objDT.Rows.Count != 1)
{
     DataRow x = objDT.Rows[0];
     var value1 = x["column1"]; // and so on
     //..do whatever
}
else
{
    if (objDT==null)
    {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("No data returned");
    }

    if (objDT.Rows.Count != 1)
    {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Multiple values returned where only one expected."); 
    }
}
```